# Let fragment wait for asynctask finished?

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I use fragments with viewPager. One of fragment use asynctask to download data. Now the problem is the task hasn't finish but fragment's onCreateView return already. 
Can I update fragment while task finished? I tried to call view.invalidate() is not working.

```
 public class LineChartFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Background().execute();
        return view;
    }
}

class Background extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (haveInternet()) {
            getter();
        }
        return null; 
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //UPDATE fragment
                    ....
                    view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), dataset, renderer);
                    ....
                    view.invalidate();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this 
[Calling a class from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918132/calling-a-class-from-a-fragment)

inflate a linearLayout and add chart view to the layout. Thanks!